# Get AppShortcuts provided by an app

Tags: android, android-appshortcut, app-shortcut

If I know an apps package name, how can I get a list of all available app shortcuts?

I can get my own apps shortcuts with the `ShortcutManager` like described here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html, but how do I get a list of another apps shortcuts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only app that has access to other apps shortcuts is the default launcher, as determined by [hasShortcutHostPermission()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/LauncherApps.html#hasShortcutHostPermission()).

For the default launcher app, they can use [getShortcuts()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/LauncherApps.html#getShortcuts(android.content.pm.LauncherApps.ShortcutQuery,%20android.os.UserHandle)) to get the list of shortcuts.

Comment: This means, for a sidebar like app it's impossible to get those shortcuts? Thanks though, this answers my question.

Comment: That's correct, yes. Not even non-default launchers can get the shortcuts.

Comment: Note that this is true for dynamic shortcuts. Static shortcuts are just `<meta-data>` entries and are public to anyone who wants to rummage through the `PackageManager`.

Comment: Static shortcuts would already be enough for me, as even this is a feature I would like to implement. Will I have to parse the manifest manually (like I do it to retrieve an icon packs image definitions for example) or is there a way to retrieve the desired intents from the `PackageManager`? I can't use the `LauncherApps` service for this if I understant that correctly

Comment: I've opened a feature request on the issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/256148980